# Accuracy doesn't match in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras to classify images. I am following the [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). The accuracy from  predict_generator is not matching with the accuracy obtained from the confusion matrix, which I am computing using the scikit-learn package. I have included the relevant snippet of the code below

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np
import theano
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
y_actual = np.ones((nb_test_samples),dtype = int)
y_actual[0:2817] = 0

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
             featurewise_std_normalization=False,
             samplewise_std_normalization=False,
     rescale = 1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    train_data_dir,
                    target_size = (img_width,img_height),
                    batch_size = 32,
                    class_mode = 'binary')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            test_data_dir,
                    target_size = (img_width,img_height),
                    batch_size = 32,
            class_mode = 'binary',
            shuffle = False         )

model.fit_generator(
                    train_generator,
                    samples_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
                    nb_epoch = nb_epoch,
                    validation_data = test_generator,
                    nb_val_samples = nb_test_samples)

score =   model.evaluate_generator(
                      test_generator,
                      4938)
print "Test fraction correct (Accuracy) = {:.2f}".format(score[1])
prediction = model.predict_generator(test_generator,nb_test_samples)

for i in xrange(0,len(prediction)):
    if prediction[i]<0.5:
       prediction[i] = 0
    else:
       prediction[i] = 1

#y_predicted = test_generator.classes
print np.sum(prediction)
CM = confusion_matrix(y_actual,prediction)
print CM
```

If I use y_predicted, I get a perfectly diagonal confusion matrix, when the console output shows an accuracy of 70% which doesn't make any sense at all. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem. Did you fix this?

Comment: @YimingYan I haven't been able to fix this. Have you been able to make any progress into this?

Comment: Did you fixed it ? Kindly explain how you did.

Answer (score 2):

The score method used in keras **`does not`** calculate accuracy like the sklearn's [`accuracy_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) method. Check the internal implementation of [`evaluate`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#evaluate-method) method to understand more. If you want to calculate accuracy, I suggest you to use sklearn's `accuracy_score` by getting the predictions or manually calculate if it is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. Just so that I have understood it correctly, in this link, https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html, accuracies of ~91% are reported using VGG net. So, this might not be 91% or 90% or whatever that Keras reports?