# Keras categorical_crossentropy loss (and accuracy)

Tags: keras, categorical-data, reference-request, loss-function

When training a neural network with [keras](https://keras.io/) for the categorical_crossentropy loss, how exactly is the loss defined? I expect it to be the average over all samples of
$$\textstyle\text{loss}(p^\text{true}, p^\text{predict}) = -\sum_i p_i^\text{true} \log p_i^\text{predict}$$
but couldn't find a definitive answer in the [docs](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy) nor in the [code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py). An authoritative reference is desirable.

Looking at the code I'm not sure if the computation is delegated to [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)/[theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#theano.tensor.nnet.nnet.categorical_crossentropy).

(There is an [analogous question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/how-does-keras-calculate-accuracy) concerning the accuracy; the [code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py) is clearer, but I don't see a call to mean()?)

PS.
From this code, it appears that loss and accuracy are computed as in `loss_and_acc(...)` but **before** the last training epoch (keras version 2.0.4, same results for tensorflow and theano backend).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint, seed

from keras import __version__ as keras_version
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

N = 4 # Classes
S = 10 # Samples

nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Dense(input_dim=1, units=N, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
nn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

seed(7)
X = np.random.random((S, 1))
Y = np.vstack([np.eye(1, N, k=randint(0, N)) for _ in range(S)])
#for (x, y) in zip(X, Y) : print(x, y)

def loss_and_acc(NN, X, Y) :
    loss = []
    acc  = []
    for (p, q) in zip(Y, NN.predict(X)) :
        loss += [ -sum(a*np.log(b) for (a, b) in zip(p, q) if (b != 0)) ]
        acc  += [ np.argmax(p) == np.argmax(q) ]
    return (np.mean(loss), np.mean(acc))

print("Keras version: ", keras_version)

for _ in range(10) :
    print("Before:  loss = {}, acc = {}".format(*loss_and_acc(nn, X, Y)))
    H = nn.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, verbose=0).history
    print("History: loss = {}, acc = {}".format(H['loss'][-1], H['acc'][-1]))
```

Output:

```
Using Theano backend.
Keras version:  2.0.4
Before:  loss = 1.3843669414520263, acc = 0.2
History: loss = 1.3843669891357422, acc = 0.20000000298023224
Before:  loss = 1.3834303855895995, acc = 0.2
History: loss = 1.3834303617477417, acc = 0.20000000298023224
Before:  loss = 1.3824962615966796, acc = 0.3
History: loss = 1.3824962377548218, acc = 0.30000001192092896
Before:  loss = 1.381564486026764, acc = 0.3
History: loss = 1.3815644979476929, acc = 0.30000001192092896
Before:  loss = 1.380635154247284, acc = 0.3
History: loss = 1.380635142326355, acc = 0.30000001192092896
Before:  loss = 1.3797082901000977, acc = 0.3
History: loss = 1.3797082901000977, acc = 0.30000001192092896
Before:  loss = 1.378783941268921, acc = 0.2
History: loss = 1.378783941268921, acc = 0.20000000298023224
Before:  loss = 1.3778621554374695, acc = 0.2
History: loss = 1.3778622150421143, acc = 0.20000000298023224
Before:  loss = 1.3769428968429565, acc = 0.2
History: loss = 1.3769428730010986, acc = 0.20000000298023224
Before:  loss = 1.3760262489318849, acc = 0.3
History: loss = 1.3760262727737427, acc = 0.30000001192092896
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using keras with tensorflow backend. I checked and the **categorical_crossentropy** loss in keras is defined as you have defined. This is the part of code (not the whole function definition)-

```
def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
    if not from_logits:
        # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
        output /= tf.reduce_sum(output, axis, True)
        # manual computation of crossentropy
        _epsilon = _to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
        output = tf.clip_by_value(output, _epsilon, 1. - _epsilon)
    return - tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(output), axis)
```

As you can see in last line, it is returning the sum of product of true values and log of output values for each observation. You can find complete function definition [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py) in line 3176.

For theano backend, it should be same. You can check [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/theano_backend.py) in line 1622.