# Keras model evaluation accuracy vs. observation

Tags: keras, tensorflow, accuracy

I am a newbie here and trying to make sense out of the scores from `model.evaluate` from what I am actually seeing in `model.predict`

I have a created a CNN model for the Google Audio Set data and achieved a 99%+ accuracy on training.

Here is how I do the prediction

```py
model = load_model('model_audioset.h5')
for x, y in unbal_generator:
  score = model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
  pred_y = model.predict(normalized_x)
```

Here is what I am seeing for one specific iteration of `x` and `y` from `model.evaluate`

```
model.metrics_names = {list: 2} ['loss', 'acc']
 0 = {str} 'loss'
 1 = {str} 'acc'

score = {list: 2} [0.03851451724767685, 0.9905123114585876]
 0 = {float64} 0.03851451724767685
 1 = {float64} 0.9905123114585876
```

Here is a readable output from `model.predict` and comparing it to `y`

[image: Actual vs. Expected]

**Wondering how Keras came up with an accuracy score of `99.05` for this output? Clearly, the predicted classes are not the same as expected**

---

I am using a `binary_crossentropy` loss function and `sigmoid` activation in the predictions layer as classes are NOT mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think accuracy is not a good metric for this case as `y_actual` and `y_expected` have most values `0` and the length of `y_actual` is quite big too.

So the accuracy calculation using an equation like `K.mean(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)))` ([Reference](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/how-does-keras-calculate-accuracy/14742#14742)) is not a good metric on model performance